# In IdentityServer4, how do you securely store the ReturnUrl?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am developing an identity server 4 dotnet core application so this is as much as a dotnet question than and IDS4 question. One example of state I need to maintain between pages (login, signup etc...) is the returnUrl. The application I'm migrating from used to store it in a session variable but, as I understand, unless I run a persistent session strategy, this won't scale well.

So currently, I'm passing it around as a field in each View Model used by each view so it can be returned. Is this a sound approach? I'll be needing other fields to be passed around as well so I'm wondering whether this is a secure and logical way to do it.

Comment: The return URL is usually passed as part of the login process. Can you show what you are actually trying to do and how the default behavior does not work for you?

Comment: Our login process includes links to signup and other login options such as internal logins so I need to make sure to pass the returnURL to those pages too. So the issue lies in the fact that the user can go back and forth between these pages in different ways.

Comment: Share us what you have tried and where it did not work. What are `internal logins`? Do you have any redirect issue for signup or internal logins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So currently, I'm passing it around as a field in each View Model used by each view so it can be returned. Is this a sound approach?

Yes, how you choose to pass it around is up to you, I choose this same approach. You could use `TempData`, Sessions or even localStorage as an alternative. I think having it in the models (view models) is a good approach because you are explicitly specifying where you want the return url to exist, otherwise it might persist in context that you wouldn't want.

Now the security question because obviously you might be able to see the return url in the browser address field.

As part of Identity Server 4 setup you specify which return url's you are allowed to redirect back to, so I don't think there is any harm in having the users see the redirect url.

Something to consider is what if the user would share the url to someone else in the middle of the authentication process, would they be able to resume from that part of the process that the initial user has stopped? is this something you want in your app?

If you mean reliably instead of securely, write tests which will provide you with confidence that your code works.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs. Regarding security, dotnet core OAuth uses a nonce to prevent replays so I think that part is covered.